# C# Windows Forms ListView get selected row values

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer

I have a `ListView` populated by a SQL db and want to be able to edit the values once I select a row and click the edit button.

When I click the "edit" button the values from the selected row should be set in the textboxes, but I get this error "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"
Why isn't this working?

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtid.Text = lvBrands.SelectedItems["id"].Text.ToString();  
        this.txtName.Text = lvBrands.SelectedItems["name"].Text.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the values of all the objects referenced in the method? (at least one of them is null)

Comment: yes.. bith of them are null... but why ? I have also tried to use [0] index instead of the column name... stil doesn't work

Comment: i think you need to attach the code that initiates your lvBrands if any chance of a solution EDIT: Actually i think if you just put a breakpoint in and make sure that the exact text in selected items is `id` and `name` you might find your answer

Comment: if your ListView is in report mode (i.e. it looks like a grid) then you will need the SubItems property. lvBrands.SelectedItems gets you each items in the list view - SubItems gets you the columns. So lvBrands.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0] is the second column value

Comment: @Rob thats it :) that was the solution :) thank you... how do i mark your answer as the solution ?

Comment: I think I have to post it as an answer(which I have just done)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your ListView is in report mode (i.e. it looks like a grid) then you will need the SubItems property. `lvBrands.SelectedItems` gets you each items in the list view - SubItems gets you the columns. So `lvBrands.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0]` is the second column value.